# How to separate sodium carbonate from sodium hydroxide?

Tags: purification, separation-techniques

I got a drain cleaner in dust form, which consists of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$. I wanted to extract the $\ce{NaOH}$ so I tried to heat the mixture in order to just melt the sodium hydroxide, but it didn't really work as expected. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: @Mithoron Well, I managed to melt it. The melting point of NaOH according to Wikipedia is 323°C not a difficult temperature to achieve. The idea was that by heating the mixture to let's say to 400°C would melt the NaOH but not the Na2CO3 which melts at 851°C and separate them this way. What I didn't know is that Na2CO3 dissolves in liquid NaOH so separation in this way is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a forum](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=66228) which discusses the similar problem of separating sodium hydroxide and sodium carbonate from drain cleaner. The solution is taken from there(slightly edited):

> This is relatively easy because sodium carbonate is practically
>   insoluble in 50% sodium hydroxide solution so a glass frit type filter
>   is needed to remover the insoluble sodium carbonate. Most commercial
>   sodium hydroxide contains only a little sodium carbonate from
>   absorption of atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$. So for carbonate free sodium
>   hydroxide solution, make up one litre at a time of say 60% solution.
>   To do this, add about 300g of sodium hydroxide pellets of flakes to
>   500ml of ice-cold water in a large beaker and stirr until practically
>   dissolved, cover and leave to cool . Allow it to cool to about 20-25 C
>   and the add another 300g of sodium hydroxide and stirr until most has
>   dissolved (much less heat is generated on the second addition), dilute
>   to one litre, pour into a 1 L thick-walled polythene bottle and leave
>   it to stand for about 1 month in a cool place and then decant the
>   clear sodium hydroxide solution.
>
> If the material is say 50% sodium carbonate do the following:
>
> Add 500g of mixed sodium salts to 500ml of ice-cold water, stirr the
>   slurry periodically for a couple of hours and then filter through a
>   glass frit funnel (a vacuum filtration set-up will be needed) and wash
>   the cake with a little water, say 50-100ml, to remove most of the
>   remaining caustic soda; some sodium carbonate will dissolve but this
>   will precipitate on the next addition. The cake will be almost pure
>   sodium carbonate but you can always treat it with saturated sodium
>   bicarbonate solution to ensure that it is.
>
> The clear filtrate should be placed in a calibrated vessel and another
>   500g of material added and again stirred periodically for a couple of
>   hours then filter and wash as before. Hopefully there should be about
>   700-800ml of very strong sodium hydroxide solution. Place it in a
>   polythene bottle and let it stand of a month so the sodium carbonate
>   can crystallize out, decant the clear solution and dilute as required.
>
> NOTE:
>
> - 60% caustic soda solution is rather viscous and will not
>     filter without suction even on a fairly coarse frit, 50% is still
>     pretty viscous and difficult to filter.
> - The sodium carbonate that
>     crystallises out sinks very slowly hence the long standing time.
> - Sodium carbonate dissolves rather slowly in water form some reason so
>     with vacuum filtation the residence time of the wash water will
>     actually dissolve very little sodium carbonate, too much wash water
>     will dilute the solution below 50% and make the carbonate more
>     soluble.
> - Hot 50% caustic soda solution is extremely aggresive
>     towards skin! When handling strong sodium hydroxide solutions, keep a
>     bowl full of dilute citric around in case of emergency.
>
> There are other method such as treating a more dilute solution with
>   slaked lime, filtering (difficult because the precipitate is fine
>   grained) and evaporating down.

Comment: **SAFETY** RE:keep a bowl full of dilute citric around in case of emergency. // You need a lot more than a bowl full of citric acid. You should have eye glasses, an apron, gloves, an eye wash, and a safety shower in case of an accident. You should also not be working alone with such chemicals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I didn't know that solubility of Na2CO3 decreases when NaOH is presented. That explains the white precipitate in an exerinment I did using the drain cleaner.